# setState can't read property of undefined, even it is

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I'm facing a weird behavior of React.js. Here is my function:

```js
let [filters, setFilters] = useState({
   search: '',
   sortBy: null,
   filter: null,
   pageNumber: '1',
   pageSize: '10',
});

if (filters.sortBy === null) {
   const newFiltering = { ...filters, sortBy: {} }
   newFiltering.sortBy[target] = '1'
   setFilters({ ...newFiltering })
}
```

So the problem I'm facing is that I get this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sortBy')
```

Which basically makes no sense, as the property exits. I also tried to do it in one line, doesn't work:

```js
setFilters({ ...filters, sortBy: { [target]: '1' } })
```

To make more clear, the problem appears when we set the Filters, and the target inside somehow.

Comment: Is `target` a variable? Because if not, this is a typo and you need to wrap it in quotes `sortBy['target']`

Comment: so target is the value of the object I want to make, sortBy: {elementName: '1'}

Comment: Does the `target` variable have a value at the time this is called?

Comment: yes it does, i have checked it

Comment: I've just tried this in a sandbox and it appears to work correctly, it seems like something else in your code is causing the issue. We'll need to see a "working" (or, reproducing the failure) example of it to be able to help. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I tried it and it works. Is it at the `newFiltering.sortBy` line you get the error?

Comment: Maybe you have somewhere a useEffect hook or a method who is updating your filters object.

Comment: I think the error is here. `if (filters.sortBy === null)`. Can you try it like this? `if (filters?.sortBy) { // codes }`. Or The error is `[target]`, we need more codes to solve it.

Comment: I found that somewhere else the problem was